# How to Sum cells that contain specific text within certain date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

if anyone could help that would be great. In Excel i have Dates in Column A, Text in F and Values in k.

Heres the formula I have currently:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F:F,"*Text*"),SUMIFS(K:K,A:A,">="&Q88,A:A,"<="&R88)*AND(SUMIF(F:F,"*Busy*",K:K),"No"))
```

Q88 is 01.01.2022
R88 is 31.01.2022

The date range would be dragged down for each month.

However all this does is see if the values are in the date range, then adds everything that contains the "Text", ignoring the date range.

[image]

Edit: i have added image, where the 'x' is where values should be, and text i am trying to extract is the text after the - 'jack' 'deceunick' etc

Comment: why a COUNTIF() then SUMIFS() and finally a SUMIF()? surely setting criteria in SUMIFS() would be sufficient or are you just copying existing bits together?

Comment: Solved: =SUMIFS($K:$K,$F:$F,"*Busy*",$A:$A,">="&DATE(2022,1,1),$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2022,1,31)) Thanks for the help

Comment: @ap306 post in answer to accept and close, so that it helps someone in the future.